# How to convert c# object to json object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I write this code:

```
var filesNames = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Image"))
                          .Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x));
var imgUrls = filesNames.Select(x => ResolveUrl(String.Format("~/Image/{0}",  x))).ToArray();

string[][] newKeys = imgUrls.Select(x => new string[] { x }).ToArray();
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

string json = jss.Serialize(newKeys);
Response.Write(json);
```

that code correctly convert imgUrl to json object and response result is:

```
[["/Image/t1.jpg"],["/Image/t2.jpg"],["/Image/t3.jpg"],["/Image/t4.jpg"]]
```

How can i add "url" fields to my json object?

for example i want convert to this:

```
[["url:","/Image/t1.jpg"],["url:","/Image/t2.jpg"],["url:","/Image/t3.jpg"],["url:","/Image/t4.jpg"]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map the `imgUrls` into anonymous objects instead of string arrays:

```
var newKeys = imgUrls.Select(x => new { url = x }).ToArray();

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = jss.Serialize(newKeys);
Response.Write(json);
```